# Cant access Mosquitto MQTT broker from client on local network

Tags: networking

I have a 20.04 server installed with Mosquitto MQTT broker.
It works fine when using the server on the local localhost

> mosquitto_pub -t 'test/topic' -m 'helloWorld

However trying to use "MQTT Explorer" on a windows-machine on the same local network fails. The client just shows "Disconnected from Server".
(I have tried ti use the MQTT broker on another server (Home Assistant) and there the MWTT Explorer client works fine)

When starting mosquitto in verbose mode "-v" I see traces when using local host client but nothing from the windows client.
Putty works from the windows server on same IP address.
I just can figure out how to troubleshoot this issue, input greatly appreciated..

Comment: Have you updated UFW for port 8883? If not, you'll never be able to connect from outside the machine: `sudo ufw allow 8883`

Comment: Hello,I tried that now but still the same, apart from that putty also get blocked when activating the UFW.
Since I am on the local network I thought I didnt need UFW - do I really need that? also putty is working from the same PC that I try to use the MQTT client so connectivity must be OK..
Any other thoughts would be appreciated..

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tested with port 1883. "localhost" works fine with client on the same host. When I use the local IP of the host or the hostname it does not work at all (even if the client is on the same host). "sudo ufw allow 1883" did not help. The ufw status is inactive anyway. The machine running the broker can be reached by a ping inside my LAN. Ping to IP respectively hostname works both fine.